# Variant type and non, with same name

Tags: typelite

i've tried to use typelite with entity framework and Identity framework.
in identity framework exists various types in the format `TypeName<Tkey>` and `TypeName: TypeName<String>`.
typelite correctly exports the types, but this behaviour is not possible in typescript, how should i work around that ?

Class:

```
namespace DTO
{
    [TypeLite.TsClass]
    public class Test : Test<String>
    {
    }

    public class Test<TKey>
    {
        public TKey Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Configuration 1:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithReference("Enums.ts")
    .ForLoadedAssemblies();
#>
```

Output 1, here the error is: Type '`Test<TKey>`' recursively references itself as a base type.

```
declare module DTO {
    interface Test extends DTO.Test<string> {
    }
    interface Test<TKey> {
        Id: TKey;
        Name: string;
    }
}
```

Configuration 2:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithReference("Enums.ts")
    .ForLoadedAssemblies()
    .WithTypeFormatter((type, f) => "I" + ((TypeLite.TsModels.TsClass)type).Name);
#>
```

Output 2, here the variant Type got the I too and things got messed up badly

```
declare module DTO {
    interface IUser {
        Id: string;
        Name: string;
        Surname: string;
        UserName: string;
        Email: string;
        Roles: string[];
    }
    interface ITest extends DTO.ITest {
    }
    interface ITest {
        Id: ITKey;
        Name: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more elaborate example: original C# file, and resulting typescript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both generic and non-generic types with the same name, in the same namespace, you have to give them a slightly different name.

Change the model definition to:

```
var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithReference("Enums.ts")
    .ForLoadedAssemblies();
ts.WithTypeFormatter((t, f) => GenerateTypeName(t, f, ts.ScriptGenerator));
```

Add this at the end:

```
<#+
    private string GenerateTypeName(TsType tsType, ITsTypeFormatter f, TsGenerator gen)
    {
        TsClass tsClass = (TsClass) tsType;

        string name = tsClass.Name;
        if (!tsClass.GenericArguments.Any())
            return name;

        name += "_" + tsClass.GenericArguments.Count;

        name += "<" + string.Join(",", tsClass.GenericArguments.Select(arg =>
        {
            string suffix = "";
            var argCol = arg as TsCollection;
            if (argCol != null)
            {
                suffix = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("[]", argCol.Dimension));
            }
            return gen.GetFullyQualifiedTypeName(arg) + suffix;
        })) + ">";

        return name;
    }
#>
```

It will generate:

```
declare module DTO {
    interface ITest extends DTO.ITest_1<string> {
    }
    interface ITest_1<TKey> {
        Id: TKey;
        Value: string;
    }
}
```